# If a child object has an attribute=True then update all others to attribute=False

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following model:

```
class AddressOfUser(AddressMixin, BaseModel):

    __tablename__ = 'adrusr_addressofuser'

    user = db.relationship('User', backref='addresses')
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    default = db.Column('adrusr_default', db.Boolean, default=False)
    first_name = db.Column('adrusr_first_name', db.String)
    last_name = db.Column('adrusr_last_name', db.String)
    phone = db.Column('adrusr_phone', db.String)
```

so when a user creates an address they can set that address to default by the `default` attribute to True using a checkbox in the form that is used to create the address.

The problem is that the user can set multiple addresses to default and that's a problem cause we won't be able to know which address to use as the default one so how can I make that if the latest address registered by the user is set as default so the rest of the addresses won't be default anymore? In other words if the latest element of has the attribute `default = True` then previous addresses should have `default = False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the sibling objects using "after_insert" and "after_update" events. In the following example, if an Address is inserted or updated with `is_default=True` then the event handler will force all other Address entries for that particular User to be `is_default=False`.

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/66027263/2144390
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship

connection_uri = "sqlite://"
engine = db.create_engine(
    connection_uri,
    future=True,
    echo=True,
)

Base = declarative_base()


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    is_default = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f"<Address(user={self.user}, address='{self.address}'"
            f", is_default={self.is_default})>"
        )


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User(id={self.id}, name='{self.name}')>"


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def _remove_other_default_addrs(mapper, connection, target):
    if target.is_default:
        session = db.inspect(target).session
        session.query(Address).filter(
            Address.user_id == target.user_id
        ).filter(Address.id != target.id).filter(
            Address.is_default == True
        ).update(
            values={"is_default": False}, synchronize_session="evaluate"
        )


@event.listens_for(Address, "after_insert")
def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    _remove_other_default_addrs(mapper, connection, target)


@event.listens_for(Address, "after_update")
def receive_after_update(mapper, connection, target):
    _remove_other_default_addrs(mapper, connection, target)


with db.orm.Session(engine, future=True) as session:
    gord = User(name="Gord")
    gord_old_addr = Address(user=gord, address="123 Old Ave", is_default=True)
    session.add_all([gord, gord_old_addr])
    session.commit()
    print(f">>> gord_old_addr.is_default is {gord_old_addr.is_default}")
    # >>> gord_old_addr.is_default is True

    gord_new_addr = Address(user=gord, address="567 New Blvd", is_default=True)
    session.add(gord_new_addr)
    session.flush()
    print(">>> session flushed")
    print(f">>> gord_old_addr.is_default is {gord_old_addr.is_default}")
    # >>> gord_old_addr.is_default is False
```