# Create one-to-one and one-to-many between two tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What I'm trying to do seems simple. I'd like to have a parent Organization which has child Groups. However, one group will be the "main_group". Each Organization should have a main group. Each Group should have a reference to the Organization in which it belongs.

I've been able to create_all and use these Models but in my tests when I do a drop_all, I get a

`sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError: Can't sort tables for DROP; an unresolvable foreign key dependency exists between tables: groups, organizations.  Please ensure that the ForeignKey and ForeignKeyConstraint objects involved in the cycle have names so that they can be dropped using DROP CONSTRAINT.`

Here is a minimum example to show what I'm trying to do. I've left some commented lines in to show what all I've tried.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Boolean, Date, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column

Base = declarative_base()


class Organization(Base):
    __tablename__ = "organizations"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))

    ### Define one-to-one with Group
    main_group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("groups.id"))
    main_group = relationship(
        "Group",
        # uselist=False,
        # back_populates="organization",
        foreign_keys=[main_group_id],
        primaryjoin="Group.id==Organization.main_group_id",
        post_update=True
        # backref="organization"
    )

    ####
    ## Defines the one-to-many collection with Group
    # groups = relationship(
    #     "Group",
    #     uselist=True,
    #     # foreign_keys="Group.organization_id",
    #     primaryjoin="Group.id==Organization.main_group_id",
    #     # back_populates="organization",
    # )


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))

    organization_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("organizations.id"), nullable=False)
    organization = relationship(
        "Organization",
        uselist=False,
        # backref="groups",
        foreign_keys=[organization_id],
        primaryjoin="Group.organization_id==Organization.id",
        # primaryjoin="Group.id==Organization.main_group_id",
        post_update=True,
    )


from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker

conn_string = "sqlite:///example.sql"
engine = create_engine(conn_string)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  # here we create all tables
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

new_org = Organization(name="my new org")
print(new_org)
session.add(new_org)
org = session.query(Organization).get(1)
new_group = Group(name="my main group", organization=org, organization_id=org.id)
new_org.main_group = new_group

session.commit()


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

Comment: Rather than maintain a foreign key in the parent that points to a specific child as the "main group" you could maintain a flag (boolean field) in the child object that identifies the "main group" and update it using event handlers as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079723/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

## From The Docs

There is actually an example pretty similar to what you want here, which uses an explicitly named foreign key, `fk_favorite_entry`:

[rows-that-point-to-themselves-mutually-dependent-rows](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_persistence.html#rows-that-point-to-themselves-mutually-dependent-rows)

That doesn't seem to fully solve the drop warning, which maybe seems to be dialect dependent.  You can fully solve it with `use_alter=True` which is explained here:

[creating-dropping-foreign-key-constraints-via-alter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#creating-dropping-foreign-key-constraints-via-alter)

## Likely Solution

Best case would be to name the atypical constraint and to set `use_alter=True` on it as well.

```py
class Organization(Base):
    # ...
    main_group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("groups.id", name="fk_main_group", use_alter=True))
    # ...
```